# iOS - sharing failure but only when Facebook iOS app not installed

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, sdk, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm currently using the iOS Facebook SDK to share text, links and pictures but am seeing strange behavior when the user doesn't have the iOS Facebook app installed.

The post is failing with the dreaded "An error occurred. Please try later" message. However. the fact that it all works when the user has the FB iOS app installed on the device makes me think there must be some strange config issue here - has anyone else seen this?

The scenarios are as follows:

Facebook iOS app not installed - FAILS

1. User logs in to FB and the app pops up the embedded browser for
   username/password - ok
2. User enters their username/password and is asked to authorise the app if necessary - ok
3. User tries to share some content - FAIL with "An error occurred.. Please try
           later"

Facebook iOS app installed - SUCCESS

1. User logs in to FB via the app and credentials are pulled from the iOS FB app - ok
2. User is asked to authorise the app if necessary - ok
3. User tries to share some content - ok, works every time

Perhaps I'm missing something obvious but I don't see what could be causing the failure of the first of these scenarios when the second works just fine.

I've checked the obvious things e.g.

- FB app isn't in Sandbox mode
- app id is being passed to the server in the request to post content
- app id is correct

There must be some sort of config setting I've missed - any thoughts?

Comment: hello jimmy, i also faced the same error and i just changed on Facebook app settings like sandbox mode and etc.. and then it works fine for me. so i think that there is no any mistake in your code just need to set exact parameters in FB APP settings in facebook developer page.

Comment: Thanks. I assumed this might be the case but I can't find anything that looks incorrect in the FB app :-(